# How to custom sort via mysql?

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
name    | 2013 | 2014
Adam    |    8 |    3
James   |    2 |    1
Total   |   18 |    9
Vince   |    8 |    5
```

This table is imported from Excel via csv

How do I get the result to look like this:

```
name    | 2013 | 2014
Adam    |    8 |    3
James   |    2 |    1
Vince   |    8 |    5
Total   |   18 |    9
```

I want to sort the results by "name", and put "Total" in the bottom of the result.

Comment: See normalization. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`.

**Query**

```
select * from your_table_name
order by case when name = 'Total' then 1 else 0 end,
name;
```

Comment: Yes, I think its possible. Just share the scenario